# Dynamic Programming, Arithmetic Progression, Time complexity issues

Tags: math, dynamic-programming

Given an array of size n (1<=n<=200000) with each entry a[i] ( 1<=a[i]<=100), find all the number of subsequences that form Arithmetic progression.
Subsequences are the sequences where you can leave any number of elements in the original sequence.
For example, the sequence A,B,D is a subsequence of A,B,C,D,E,F obtained after removal of elements C, E and F. The relation of one sequence being the subsequence of another is a preorder.

I have written O(n^2) solution using DP. But n^2 = 10^10. So, It'll not get accepted.
Here is what I did.
Pseudocode:

```
for every element A[i]:
    for every element A[k] such that k<i:
        diff = A[i] - A[k] + 100:      (adding 100, -ve differences A.P.)
            dp[i][diff] += dp[i-1][diff] + 1;

for every element A[i]:
    for every diff, d:
        ans = ans + dp[i][d];
return ans;
```

This is giving correct output but TLE for 3 big cases.

P.S. Please suggest better solution..!!

Is divide and conquer optimization DP required here?? If yes, tell me how to build the solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "where you can leave any number of elements in the original sequence"? Must the elements of the arithmetic progression be consecutive in the array? (It seems not, from your pseudocode, but your stated requirement is not clear.)

Comment: @Rory Daulton  Not necessarily consecutive. A subsequence is a sequence that can be derived from another sequence by deleting some elements without changing the order of the remaining elements.
For example, the sequence A,B,D  is a subsequence of A,B,C,D,E,F obtained after removal of elements C,  E and F. The relation of one sequence being the subsequence of another is a preorder.

Comment: The definition you give is the most common one, but I seen others. Thanks for the clarification.